# Alarmbell on saving .py file if linting errors using flake8

Tags: hooks, flycheck

I'd like to configure Emacs to play an audible noise when saving my `.py` files but only if there is a linting error present.

I currently have flycheck linting done on the fly and autopep8 settings applied on saving with the following configuration...

```
;; Use flycheck rather than flymake with elpy
(when (require 'flycheck nil t)
  (setq elpy-modules (delq 'elpy-module-flymake elpy-modules))
  (add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode))
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq flycheck-python-pylint-executable "~/.virtualenvs/dskit/bin/pylint")
            (setq flycheck-pylintrc "~/.emacs.d/settings/.pylintrc")))

;; enable autopep8 formatting on save
(require 'py-autopep8)
(add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook 'py-autopep8-enable-on-save)
```

...and was thinking that a hook added to `'py-autopep8-enable-on-save` might be the way forward, but am still on the starting slopes of the Lisp learning curve and would appreciate any pointers or suggestions.

Comment: You'll need some way to tell whether or not there exists >1 errors in the file.  I don't see any variables that store the number of linting errors in the file.  It looks like `python.el` and `elpy` use `python-check` to call `flake8`.  When run with `M-x`, it returns an error code.  If you can find a way to call that in the background, you could write a function that calls `flake8` and, depending on the return code, plays a sound.  You'd want to add that to the `before-save-hook`.  `py-autopep8-enable-on-save` is just a wrapper for that.

Comment: It looks like you might be able to use something like this: `(call-process "flake8" nil t nil "program.py")`.  This returns the output from running `flake8 program.py`. Hopefully that's enough to get you down the right path.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I'll report back when I've had time to play around.